# Oneplus 11R App Icon Color not changing

Tags: android-13, oneplus

I have installed Pix Material You Light/Dark Icon Pack on my One Plus 11R, and applied using Oneplus Wallpaper & Style (Icons section). And, When I change wallpaper, icon color is not changing accordingly. How to Solve this?